# #define Issue with #pragma

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, pragma, iar

I have a problem with the #define in C
I am using MSP430F5418 with IAR EW 5.10
I have a pragma called location which will put the next declaring variable to the specified segment.
In the below example a will put into the segment called myseg and b is not.

```
 #pragma location="myseg"
 static const char a[] = "amma";
 static const char b[] = "amrita";
```

I have a lot of constants like this.
I want to know whether I could do something like this...

```
#define TYPE location="myseg" \
       static const char 
#pragma TYPE a = "amma";
#pragma TYPE b = "amrita";
.....
```

so that I can avoid  `#pragma location="myseg"` before each variable declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a `#pragma` inside a `#define`, nor the other way round.

To circumvent this restriction, some compilers offer a [`_Pragma` operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) (GCC, LLVM) (`__pragma` in Visual C++) which provide the same functionality as the `#pragma` directive. This operator *can* be used in another macro. Find out whether your compiler supports such a pragma operator.

Using this, you could write:

```
#define DECLARE_IN_SEG(decl) \
    _Pragma(location="myseg") \
    static const char decl;

DECLARE_IN_SEG(a = "amma");
DECLARE_IN_SEG(b = "amrita");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In IAR we can use @ operator for that. http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=39271